# z-index не работает, в чем ошибкa, last_child

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap, z-index

Всем привет, не получается правильно вставить салотовый уголок в блоках, в чем проблема не пойму помогите разобратся, вот я пробывала через

```
        content: '';
        display: block;
        background-image:  url("storage/app/public/default/Path15.png");
        width: 6px;
        height: 11px;
        z-index: -1;

    }
```

также пробовала через создание нового блока не работает, также надо чтобы он был на двоих из шести этих  div. КАк сделать подскажите пожалуйста, спасибо[image: z]

```
<section class="sect-services">
               <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" >
                               
                                   <div class="service-item">
                                       <div class="service-item-image">
                                           <img src="{{url('/storage/'.$service->images)}}" alt="Ceramic">
                                       </div>
                                       <h4>{{$service->name}}</h4>
                                       <p class="mb-0 text-muted">{!! strip_tags($service->content) !!}</p>
                                  
                                       <div class="service-item-price">
                                           <a href="{{$service->url}}" class="button">Zobacz więcej</a>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                           </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </section>
```

```
.sect-services{

    .col-md-4{
        bottom: 72px;

    }
}


.service-item{
    box-shadow: rgba(224, 218, 218) 0 14px 19px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 14px 0px;
    border-radius: 24px;


    &::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        background-image:  url("storage/app/public/default/Path15.png");
        width: 6px;
        height: 11px;
        z-index: -1;

    }



    &:hover{
        transform: scale(1.05);
        border-color: $main-color;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) 0 0 22px;
        .service-stars{
            .fa{
                margin: 0 3px;
            }
        }

        .service-item-image{
            .fa{
                opacity: .4;
            }

            &::before{
                opacity: .7;
            }
        }
    }

    h4{
        font-family: $heading-body-font-family;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    p{
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: $body-font-family;
        padding: 0 29px;
    }
    .service-stars{
        font-size: 11px;
        color: black;
        .fa{
            margin-left: 1px;
            transition: all .5s ease;

        }
    }

    .service-item-image {
        min-height: 160px;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 22px;

        img{
            width: 180px;
        }

        .fa{
            font-size: 30px;
            color: $accent-color;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -10px;
            margin-top: -10px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all .5s ease;
        }
        &::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: '';
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            //background-color: $main-color;
            opacity: .0;
            transition: 0.5s ease;

        }
        &:hover{
            transform: scale(1.05);


            .service-item-image{
                .fa{
                    opacity: .4;
                }

                &::before{
                    opacity: .7;
                    border-radius: 24px;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .service-item-price{
        margin-bottom: 26px;
        margin-top: 22px;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: $heading-font-family;
        span{
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        .fa{
            color: $main-color;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .button{
            background-color: transparent !important;
            box-shadow:  none !important;
            color: #42525F !important;
            border: 2px solid #CFD3D7 ;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: $button-body-font-family;
            font-size: 18px;
            position: initial;
            padding: 11px 26px;

            &:hover {
               background-color: transparent;
               box-shadow: none;
               background-image: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: z-index:-1 как бы предполагает прятать элемент в самый нижний слой. А вообще тут такая мешанина, что никто разбираться не захочет. Сделайте, пожалуйста, сниппет здесь из скомпилированных данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты можешь сделать что-то на подобие этого -

html

```
<div id="last-div">
    Posledniy div s kontentom
</div>
<div id="green-corner">
    <img src="corner.png">
</div>
```

css

```
#last-div{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#green-corner{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px; /* -razmer zelenogo prostranstwa slewa kartinki */
    left: 90px; /* razmer last-div - razmer pustogo prostranstwa snizu kartinki */
}
```

Не самое оптимальное решение, но другого я пока не знаю. Надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 1):

[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) работает в связке с таким свойством как [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position).

В вашем примере отсутствует `position`, следовательно имеет значение *по-умолчанию* - `static`

> **static**
> Это значение позволяет элементу находиться в обычном его состоянии, расположенном на своем месте в документе. Свойства `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` и `z-index` не применяются к данному элементу. **Это значение по умолчанию**.

Comment: @Sevastopol', пускай)